# Is ReLU activation function unsuitable for input layer if the input data has high inter-example correlation?

Tags: neural-networks, data-preprocessing, activation-function, relu

After making a neural network using ReLU as the activation function throughout, I had a look at the *input layer* activations and noticed that about 10% of the neurons are dead on initialization (never activated). At first I assumed it was caused by the large magnitude of my inputs and/or large input layer weights, but scaling those down made no difference (which in hindsight seems obvious for ReLU).

Then I realized that the input feature vectors have high inter-example correlation, and that the linear part of the input layer is essentially taking the dot/inner product of this correlated bundle of vectors, with other random vectors. From this perspective, it seems unsurprising that some of those random vectors will have a negative dot product with the input vectors from the entire example set, and that there's nothing I can do to fix this other than changing the activation function, or de-correlating the input feature vectors by preprocessing.

Am I missing something, or are ReLU-activated input neurons unsuitable when the dataset's inputs are highly correlated between examples?

Or should I perhaps just subtract the population mean input from all the input vectors to at least center the population at the origin? (Or perhaps learn a bias parameter for each input feature before feeding it in?)

Comment: By input layer, do you mean the first hidden layer of the neural network or the input features?

Comment: @gunes The first layer of neurons. So the input features would be scaled by the input layer's weights, then (after fan-in/summing) offset by the input layer's biases (if a bias is present) then go through the input layer's activation function.

Comment: Input layer usually means input features. Nevertheless, I'm having hard time to understand how correlated input samples can affect the outputs. Each example's output should be different.

Comment: @gunes If the input vectors are clustered/bundled in a similar direction, then it seems to me there would be a random vector (randomly initialized weights from those inputs to a particular neuron) would have a significant probability of having a negative dot product with all those input vectors in the cluster/bundle, which it seems to me would mean that the neuron was born dead (if it is ReLU activated).